# Sorting objects in an array by a field value (if exist)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have the following structure:

```
var participant1 = {
    name : "bbb",
    nickname : "",
} ;

var participant2 = {
    name : "",
    nickname : "aaa"
} ;

var participant3 = {
    name : "ccc",
    nickname : ""
} ;
```

And i have an array which contain instances of structure :

```
var array = [participant3, participant1, participant2];
```

I would like to sort this array by alphabetical letter. First on name, but if name doesn't exist, i would like to use nickname to sort. The final result will be :

```
var array = [participant2, participant1, participant3];
```

(To have sorted object by "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to create a `compare` function and then use `.sort()`

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.name< b.name)
     return -1;
  else if (a.name> b.name)
    return 1;
  else
   {
      if (a.nickname< b.nickname)  return -1;
      else return 1;
   }
}

array.sort(compare);
```

Comment: Try replacing `nickname : "aaa"` with `nickname : "xxx"` for  `participant2`.

Comment: Although accepted, this answer is still wrong and only "works" by accident. Please take time to fix it.

Comment: I told you twice that your answer is wrong and gave you time to fix it. You didn't, hence the DV.

Answer (score 2):

Use this custom sortfunction

```
var arr = [participant3, participant1, participant2],
    sortFunc = function(a,b){
    if(a.name !== '' && b.name !== ''){
        return a.name > b.name;
    } else if(a.name !== ''){
        return a.name > b.nickname;
    } else if(b.name !== ''){
        return a.nickname > b.name;
    } else{
        return a.nickname > b.nickname;
    }

}

arr.sort(sortFunc);
```